# Who are these guys seen in chapter 691?

Tags: naruto

**SPOILER ALERT**

Who are these guys? What are their names and their positions?

[image]

Comment: Did you try reading the (end of) the previous chapter at all?

Comment: Hi @zibadawatimmy, What part does they explicitly state the names of these characters?

Comment: They don't. And most likely never will. They serve as little more than a superfluous demonstration of the sage's power, and witnesses to Naruto. We know little more than how they got there and the simplest facts of their identities, and I expect it to stay that way. Hope for a data book telling us more if you really want it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are the *Gokage* (lit. *Five Shadow*), the first Kages from each country. Their names haven't been told yet, but by their appearance we can deduct which *Kage* ruled which village.

**First panel:** The first *Kazekage*. I'm doubting between the third and first panel on who the first *Kazekage* might be. But given that the third panel resembles a *Tsuchikage* more, I deduct that this is the first Kazekage.

**Second panel:** First *Mizukage*. The razor teeth follow the trend of the shinobi swordsman who originated from the village of the hidden Mist.

**Third panel:** I'm guessing that this is the first *Tsuchikage*. I'm not sure because I can't base this answer on the fact that he's aged. The facial hair however does hint at a resemblance between Oonoki and other *Tsuchikage*'s.

**Fourth panel:** First *Raikage* due to hair. We can assume that he's coloured. This follows the trend that most villagers from the Hidden Cloud are in fact black.

In manga chapter 648, pages 10 - 11 and 12. We see Hashirama meeting with the first Kages. These are the same Kages as shown in the panels

Comment: So far the most sensible answer. Let's wait what the others have to say. Actually, me too is guessing which is which.

Comment: It's been pretty much confirmed in the manga chapter I listed in the edit :) My deductions are correct

Comment: @NaraShikamaru (and for Kevin) Wiki says almost 50 chapters earlier, chapter 648 we saw (in color) the first Gokage, and they indeed are the ones pictured, Using the links from here http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kage_Summit we can see all 4 of the other Gokage besides Hashirama, and they match up.